# Do we have auto array in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
auto numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};    // 'numbers' is an std::intializer_list<int>
auto num_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4} // error -> declared as an array of 'auto'
```

Why is this limitation in place?

Comment: No, we don't have auto arrays in C++. Arrays are evil, they don't know their size and get converted to pointers.

Comment: Auto deduces types not "partial types" I guess

Comment: fyi: this compiles `decltype(1) num_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`  live: https://godbolt.org/g/Yk2kJv

Comment: @Ron, no, arrays are not evil. Some programmers are, though.

Comment: @RichardCritten: what is decltype(1) good for? You can write int if you like :-) And with `int array[] = {1,2,3,4};` nothing is special.

Comment: @Ron Arrays very much do know their size. It's sizeof(Array)/sizeof(*(Array)) (and you can make it comptime error if Array isn't an array (at least C, using _Generic, but I'd bet there's a C++ version too).

Comment: @PSkocik: Or even `template <typename T, std::size_t N> constexpr std::size_t N size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }`.

Answer (score 17):

With C++17 and [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), this works just fine:

```
#include <array>
std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
int i = arr.size();  // 4
```

Comment: Is it possibly to only supply the type argument and only deduct the size?

Comment: @Moberg, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 5):

Asking [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/2069064) on language features is a notoriously difficult question to answer.

But the hopefully helpful version is: `auto` is a very simple language feature that just does full deduction, not constrained deduction. You can add some declarators, like `auto&` or `auto*`, but not all of them. As-is, it's incredibly useful. Just... not all powerful. It's often useful to start with a simple, restricted feature set and then expand later as we gain experience.

---

With Concepts, it is possible that further power may be added to declarations to do more kinds of things, like:

```
std::vector<int> foo();
std::vector<auto> v = foo();
```

Having an array of `auto` seems to fit into that mold. Definitely not in C++17, but possibly for C++20.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but it is possible to deduce the element type from an raw array list initializer and declare the array directly, as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct array_trait
{
    using element_type = T;
    array_trait(T(&&)[]);
};

decltype(array_trait({4,5,7}))::element_type a[] = {4,5,7};
```

Comment: Which then begs to be turned into a macro: `#define AUTO_ARRAY(name, values) decltype(array_trait(values))::element_type name[] = values;`  ... `AUTO_ARRAY(a, {4,5,7});`