# Why can I auto-declare pointers but not arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, auto, type-deduction

I know that "Why" questions are deprecated; I'm wondering specifically whether there is a technical reason that `auto` cannot deduce array element types. A simple example is

```
auto arr[] {1}; // does not compile
```

The type deduction *does* work for a similar indirection, pointers:

```
int i;
auto *p { &i };  // compiles
```

Both deductions seem equally doable for simple cases (and should run into similar problems, if any, for complicated types). What am I missing?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840908/do-we-have-auto-array-in-c17

Comment: Notice already the "mismatch" `&1` is a pointer, whereas `1` is not an array :) (would require `auto arr[]{{1}}`).

Comment: Who still writes C-style arrays with C++17 + std::array?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: if you want to specify only type **or** size :-)

Comment: Wow, in linked question there's an answer with 11 upvotes and not answering the question at all.

Comment: @Jans Funny, I really searched (both here and globally) and did not see that question. Vote to close as dup, if you like to. Barry's answer there is probably true (i.e., there is no technical reason, it's simply that some declarators are not allowed (yet)). But I mean, we had 7+ years to do that.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher People who are interested in the language proper.

Comment: @Jarod42 Proper point, but that's a flaw in the language. If you can say `int i = 3;` you should also be able to say `int *p = i;`. `i` is a constant address very much like `3` is a constant int. The two initializations can be transformed into each other by adding resp. removing one level of indirection on both sides; there is no inherent reason why one works and the other does not (apart from the original equivalency between ints and pointers which made `int *p = i` mean something different in K&R).